# inside for loop use value of variable i declared in for loop?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a for loop to repeat a table head, Each th has a dropdown inside. dropdown has href, i need to pass href which will send data like visit1=item , visit2=item

i dont want to hardcord visit1, visit2, ..etc, it should come with respect to the for loop

```
        @for (var i = 1; i < ViewBag.NoOfVisits + 1; i++)
                {
                    <th>
                        <p>Visit @i</p>
                        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">

                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.visit)
                                {
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="@Url.Action("Index", "ClinicalRegistryManager", new {siteId =@ViewBag.siteId, visit+@i = item})">@item</a></li>
                                }


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                }
```

see the th has dropdown inside, inside dropdown i have another foreach , inside that you can see a li with href which will be trying to send visit+@i=item , its not working,

```
  new {siteId =@ViewBag.siteId, visit+@i = item})
```

so what should i have to do to over come this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this... some one just check it out , and improve?

```
                @for (var i = 1; i < ViewBag.NoOfVisits + 1; i++)
                {
                    <th>
                        <p>Visit @i</p>
                        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">

                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="@Url.Action("Index", "ClinicalRegistryManager", new { siteId = @ViewBag.siteId })">Show all</a></li>

                                @{
                                    var array = ViewBag.visit1;
                                    switch (i)
                                    {
                                        case 1:
                                            {
                                                array = ViewBag.visit1;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 2:
                                            {
                                                array = ViewBag.visit2;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 3:
                                            {
                                                array = ViewBag.visit3;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 4:
                                            {
                                                array = ViewBag.visit4;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case 5:
                                            {
                                                array = ViewBag.visit5;
                                                break;
                                            }

                                    }
                                }

                                @foreach (var item in array)
                                {
                                    var visit = "visit" + @i;
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="~/ClinicalRegistryManager/Index?SiteId=@ViewBag.siteId&@visit=@item">@item</a></li>
                                }


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                                    }
```